# How to acces TikTok pages with selenium

Tags: linux, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to acces a TikTok page with Selenium, but when I open the page dont load.

[Page dont load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nK2fG.png)

Note: Iḿ passing a profile to Selenium that is configurated with the GoogleBot, allowed in the robots.txt TikTok page.
[Firefox Config: User-Agent Google Bot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fN3Ri.png)

```
const {Builder,By} = require('selenium-webdriver');
const firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');
let profile = '/home/rafaelgomes/.mozilla/firefox/bahfrkjt.Selenium';
let options = new firefox.Options().setProfile(profile);
let driver = new Builder()
    .forBrowser('firefox')
   .setFirefoxOptions(options)
    .build();

 

    driver.get('https://www.tiktok.com/@doarda?lang=pt_BR/');
```

Answer (score 0):

Some web applications are detecting if the browser is controlled and they have implemented mechanisms to avoid letting people to access them via selenium or any other similar tool.